# SQL Server doesn't allow to execute subquery as dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, dynamic, subquery, temp-tables

I tried to make a dynamic SQL which gets all tasks for some users

The procedure [GetAllSubExecutorsByUserId] returns IDs of all subalterns of curent user
I write these IDs into a temporary table, and after that I want to make a dynamic SQL to get all tasks from [tasks] table where "Executor" column has the value IN this temporary table

The query I wrote follows:

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(10) = 72;

DECLARE @tmp TABLE  ( Id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @tmp exec [dbo].[GetAllSubExecutorsByUserId] @Source = @UserId;

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max);

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tasks ';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE Executor IN (' + (select Id from @tmp) + ')';

EXEC(@SQL);
```

But when i run it , it gives an error:

*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

And i can't understand how to fix it, because if i run the same query (which is not a dynamic SQL it works perfectly)

the query which works is static:

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(10) = 72;

DECLARE @tmp TABLE  ( Id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @tmp exec [dbo].[GetAllSubExecutorsByUserId] @Source = @UserId;

SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE Executor IN (select Id from @tmp)
```

But I need a diynamic SQL...
Help me please to resolve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are trying to set a string value from a select that is returning more than one value. SQL does not know how to turn this list into a comma delineated one. In the prepared statement it is running as a true `IN` against a returned 'table', so it can run SET operators against that subquery table. In the dynamic query, you are essentially trying to create something like this, though:

```
...IN (1,2,3)
```

You must rewrite the dynamic query like below to get it to run just like the prepared statement:

```
'WHERE Executor IN (select Id from @tmp)'
```

If you do this, then you will have to pass the table variable into the exec though, but you will have to use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). So, your code becomes:

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(10) = 72;

DECLARE @tmp TABLE  ( Id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT @tmp exec [dbo].[GetAllSubExecutorsByUserId] @Source = @UserId;

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max);

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tasks ';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE Executor IN (select Id from @tmp)';

DECLARE @SQLParamSetup VARCHAR(150);
SET @SQLParamSetup = '@tmp TABLE  ( Id VARCHAR(10))'


EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @SQLParamSetup, @tmp ;
```

**However, another, cleaner option** would be to use a temp table (not variable), as it will stay alive throughout your connection (even in child queries)

```
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(10) = 72;

CREATE TABLE #tmp  ( Id VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO #tmp exec [dbo].[GetAllSubExecutorsByUserId] @Source = @UserId;

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max);

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tasks ';
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE Executor IN (select Id from #tmp)';

EXEC @SQL ;
```

Comment: as i understand, i should get the result of "select Id from @tmp" subquery as a CSV string ... but what about sp_executesql ?>

Comment: I do not know where you got that understanding, but that is NOT true that a subquery will convert to a CSV. I will update my answer to show how this can be used for sp_executesql as described

Comment: Justin, at the line : 
SET @SQLParamSetup = "'@tmp TABLE  ( Id VARCHAR(10))' it is something wrong... 
if I remove those double quotes (") there appears the error message "incorrect sintax near sp_executesql" can you suggest me how to adapt... thank you

Comment: Sorry, you have to EXEC the sproc that executes sql :p. I have updated the code

Comment: Justin, can you explain, why with **EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @SQLParamSetup, @tmp ;** also it doesn't execute.. 
I've created **#Executors table** as temporary, the **@SQL** query i've changed to be NVARCHAR (because **sp_executesql** expects only NVARCHAR, NTEXT and NCHAR)

`DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
 SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tasks '
 SET @SQL = @SQL + ' WHERE tasks.Executor IN (SELECT Id FROM #Executors)'

 DECLARE @ParamDef NVARCHAR(1000)
 SET @ParamDef = '#Executors TABLE (Id NVARCHAR(10))'
 Execute sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDef, #Executors` 
it gives _Incorrect syntax near '#Executors'.

Comment: Please see the bottom section of my answer. If you use a temp table (#), then you do not need (and cannot as you found out) to use the sp_executesql, you can just call EXEC. The temp table will be available to the EXEC because it lives in the parent session

Answer (score 0):

Use [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) and you can pass in the parameter.

Comment: Well what you have there is really simple and doesn't need dynamic sql so i'm guessing you have a more complicated query, but you could pass your table variable as a parameter to be used by the dynamic sql

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @ddto as char(10)='2020/10/01',
set @month= (select month(@ddto))
set @year =(select year(@ddto))

you can change in the dynamic query as following:
select column1 where
Material_Issued_to_div='''+ @div+''' and 
month(indent_date)='''+@month+'''       and 
year(indent_date)='''+@year+'''
```